# What is the difference between "schließen" and "abschließen"?

Tags: meaning

Both words of "schließen" and "abschließen" mean "conclude". What is the difference between meaning of these two words?

Comment: I would recommend to look for a more detailed dictionary, since yours seems only to give a single word and no context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Conclude" has two distinct meanings - it can mean "to bring something to an end", and it can mean "arrive at a judgment or opinion by reasoning".

"Schließen" and "abschließen" both have multiple meanings as well.

"Schließen" can simply mean *conclude* in the sense of "arrive at a conclusion by reasoning" ("Aus diesen Beobachtungen schließe ich, dass ...").
But "schließen" can also simply mean "close" as in "Please close the door".
But "schließen" never means "finish something" (at least not in Germany, it might be possible that this usage is common in Austria or Switzerland).

"Abschließen" refers to "bringing something to an end" or "finishing something", but it also has other meanings, e.g. *to lock* ("Ich habe die Tür abgeschlossen" // "I locked the door").

So they both mean "conclude", but they both target *different* meanings of "conclude", and they have some other meanings as well.

Comment: What about "Hiermit schließe ich die Verhandlung."?

Comment: @Gerhard Dort wird "Schließen" benutzt im Sinne wie bei "Die Akten schließen". Das Resultat steht fest und wird von Veränderungen geschützt. Das ist metaphorischer Gebrauch.

Comment: What about verschließen? how different is this from those two?

Comment: @LorDan "verschließen" means to physically seal something. But if you have a question about "verschließen", you should ask a new question.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think there's much difference between "abschließen" and "schließen" regarding the meaning of "to conclude s.th.". But as it's been stated before it can also mean "schließen" = "to close s.th." (like a door, or a window) and "abschließen" will mean "to lock s.th." so no stranger can open it.